# New eclipse installation using old features and plugins

Tags: linux, eclipse, plugins

I want to use a different installation of the Eclipse IDE, and drop into it some plugins and features that I already downloaded and install on a different instance of Eclipse.  How can I do that?  AFAIK, it's not as plain as copying the jar files, because Eclipse keeps some meta-data somewhere.

If it matters, the OS is Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The convention is for the meta-data for plugins to be kept in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/ So just copy those to the *workspace* for the new install. Or just copy the entire workspace if you like.

Comment: I pointed the new installation to the old workspace, but my old plugins did not work (e.g., it did not open the Prolog editor for Prolog files, although I have the Prolog plugin in the plugins dir).  There must be some other configuration other then just the plugins dir.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the old eclipse as a repository for install new software.  The directory you want is OLD_ECLIPSE/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile/

If you uncheck "group items by category" you should see the list of features you installed in your OLD_ECLIPSE.